# Conditions for bounded below Operator being continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $T: X\mapsto Y$, be a bounded below operator, meaning $\|Tx\|\geq m\|x\|$. Under what conditions is $T$ continuous (bounded from above)? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686125/about-bounded-below-operators) it was stated that it is implied directly, but how can one prove that $\operatorname{im} T$ is closed in $Y$ as it was used in that answer? Am I overlooking something? Or are there details missing?

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ an algebraic basis of $X$. Define $T:X\to \ell^1(I)$ via the linear extension of $T(a_i)=\|a_i\| i$ (here $i$ denotes the $\ell^1$-Basis element). Note that
$$\left\|T\left(\sum_i v_i a_i\right)\right\|_{\ell^1(I)} = \left\|\sum_i v_i\|a_i\|_X\ i\right\|_{\ell^1(I)}=\sum_i |v_i|\, \|a_i\|_X ≥ \left\|\sum_i v_i a_i\right\|_X$$ and thus $T$ is bounded from below.

However this map has no chance of being continuous, and the image isn't closed, it appears to me the claim is wrong.