# Bounded Below Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Example of bounded below opeartor which is unbounded on Banach space?

In case of normed space we have $T:c_{00} \to \ell^{\infty}$ defined as
$$T(x_{n})=(n x_{n})$$ is bounded below operator and unbounded.
But we need unbounded operator defined on Banach space.

Comment: What actually is your question? Please use a verb in the first sentence of your post(s).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3126808/144766), let $\ell^1(\Bbb{R})$ be the Banach space of all $\Bbb{R}$-indexed sequences which are absolutely summable, equipped with the norm
$$\|(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\Bbb{R}}\|_1 = \sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} |x_\alpha|.$$

The cardinality of $\ell^1(\Bbb{R})$ is $c$, this is because every $\Bbb{R}$-sequence in $\ell^1(\Bbb{R})$ is supported on a countable subset of $\Bbb{R}$. Since every vector space with dimension at least $c$ has dimension equal to its cardinality, it follows that $\dim \ell^1(\Bbb{R}) = c$. Therefore we can pick an $\Bbb{R}$-indexed algebraic basis $(v_\alpha)_{\alpha \in\Bbb{R}}$ for $\ell^1(\Bbb{R})$.

Define a linear map on this basis as $$T : \ell^1(\Bbb{R}) \to \ell^1(\Bbb{R}), \qquad T\left(\sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} \lambda_\alpha v_\alpha  \right) = \left(\lambda_\alpha (\alpha^2+1) \|v_\alpha\|_1\right)_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}}$$

We have
\begin{align}
\left\|T\left(\sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} \lambda_\alpha v_\alpha  \right)\right\|_1 &= \left\|\left(\lambda_\alpha (\alpha^2+1) \|v_\alpha\|_1\right)_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}}\right\|_1 \\
&= \sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} |\lambda_\alpha |(\alpha^2+1) \|v_\alpha\|_1 \\
&\ge \sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} |\lambda_\alpha |\|v_\alpha\|_1 \\
&\ge \left\|\sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{R}} \lambda_\alpha v_\alpha\right\|_1
\end{align}
so $T$ is bounded from below by $1$. On the other hand, we have
$$\frac{\|T(v_\alpha)\|_1}{\|v_\alpha\|_1} = \alpha^2+1, \qquad \text{ for all }\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$$
so $T$ cannot be bounded.